Fourier coefficients of inner and outer functions.
Let $H^2:=H^2(\mathbb{D})$ denote the Hardy-space on the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$, i.e. $H^2(\mathbb{D})=\{F\in \text{Hol}(\mathbb{D}) : \sup_{0\leq r<1} \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi |F(re^{i \theta})|^2 d\theta < +\infty \}$. Then we know that each $F\in H^2$ has an inner-outer factorization $F=e^{i \gamma} B_FS_FO_F$, where $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$, $B_F$ denotes the Blaschke-product corresponding to the zeros of $F$, $S_F$ is the singular inner function
\begin{align*}
S_F(z)= \exp \left(-\int_{\partial\mathbb{D}} \frac{e^{i\theta}+z}{e^{i\theta}-z} d \nu_F(e^{i\theta}) \right)
\end{align*}
for some finite positive singular measure $\nu_F$ (singular w.r.t. the Lebesgue-measure on $\partial \mathbb{D}$) and $O_F$ is the outer function
\begin{align*}
O_F(z)=\exp \left ( \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{e^{i\theta}+z}{e^{i\theta}-z} \log |f(e^{i\theta})| d\theta\right)
\end{align*}
I am trying to describe the Fourier coefficients of $F$. Even if I assume that $F$ has no zeros, I have no idea how to handle the inner and outer parts. Does somebody know how to describe the Fourier-coefficients of the inner and outer parts of $F$ (depending on the measure $\nu_F$ and the boundary values $f(e^{i\theta})$)? I know the question is vague, but maybe somebody can direct me to something that would help. I thought it might help to write the integral in $S_F$ as a Stieltjes integral of a singular function on $[-\pi,\pi]$, but that's about it.

remember that $H^2$ is just the analytic part of $L^2$ (in other words $\sum_{n \ge 0} a_ne^{int}, \sum |a_n|^2 < \infty$); this being said not sure exactly what you mean concretely
